# ipad 3 screen with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ipad

What does JavaScript pull out with:

```
 screen.width
```

and

```
 screen.height
```

on the ipad 3? Is it:

```
1024x768
```

Is there a 2048x1536 width/height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1024x768` so that sizing is consistent across devices.

Comment: so how can we detect that it has a display of 2048x1536 and thats its not ipad 2? Is it with window.devicePixelRatio?  any links with info would be great...

Answer (score 1):

The iPad 3 resolution is 2048×1536 pixels – which is exactly twice the current iPad resolution.

That's the user agent of the iPads:

**iPad**:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 4_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8F190 Safari/6533.18.5
```

**iPad2**:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 4_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8F191 Safari/6533.18.5
```

**iPad3**: ??

There is a way that you can detect if the user are using an iPad device:

```
// For use within normal web clients 
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;

// For use within iPad developer UIWebView
// Thanks to Andrew Hedges!
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
var isiPad = /iPad/i.test(ua) || /iPhone OS 3_1_2/i.test(ua) || /iPhone OS 3_2_2/i.test(ua);
```

But, i think the correct approach is create a interface based on the user resolution and not the user device. You can read more about Responsive Web Design, your visitors should love :)

**Bonus**
There is a tool that you can test you "responsive" design in all resolutions at the same time:
http://mattkersley.com/responsive/